# byte[] to string cutoff from oracle Db(only gets part of the data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

the problem i am facing is when i try to fetch data from the oracle Db, it only gets part of the data.
the code i am using is as follows:

```
        reportSQL = string.Format(reportSQL, actionId);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(WebPortal.Utils.WebPortalConfigManager.Instance.ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(reportSQL, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

then i try to convert using:

```
                byte[] binaryString = (byte[])reader["REPORT"];
                Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binaryString);
```

however this only returns part of the text but i can see in the dB it is complete.

Comment: What is the (DB) type of REPORT in the database?

Comment: hello! it saved as byte i believe

Comment: though it may be LONG RAW.